# jest - Is there a way to check percentage of test coverage?

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, jestjs

I used following command to run my tests and get a coverage report:

```
jest --coverage
```

now I want to check whether percentage of coverage is more than 90% or not in my script file. what should I do ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `coverageThreshold` option in your Jest configuration:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragethreshold-object

```
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 50,
        "functions": 50,
        "lines": 50,
        "statements": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```