# Jest coverage: How can I get a total percentage of coverage?

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage

In my gitlab pipeline I want to send the total percentage value to a server. But jest --coverage only gives me these large reporting files in /coverage. I can't seem to parse the total value out of it. Am I missing a parameter?

Comment: After reading the documentation, I don't think Jest can simply give you the percentage without using the report as files. I would recommend that you write a js script that reads your index file and does whatever you want with the value, and then configure your pipeline to execute this script right after the jest tests. You can also play around thresholds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794031/jest-is-there-a-way-to-check-percentage-of-test-coverage

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Thanks to Teneff's answer, I go with the coverageReporter="json-summary".

```
 jest --coverage --coverageReporters="json-summary"
```

This generates a coverage-summary.json file which can easily be parsed. I get the total values directly from the json:

```
  "total": {
    "lines": { "total": 21777, "covered": 65, "skipped": 0, "pct": 0.3 },
    "statements": { "total": 24163, "covered": 72, "skipped": 0, "pct": 0.3 },
    "functions": { "total": 5451, "covered": 16, "skipped": 0, "pct": 0.29 },
    "branches": { "total": 6178, "covered": 10, "skipped": 0, "pct": 0.16 }
  }
```

Answer (score 46):

Internally jest is using Istanbul.js to report coverage and you can modify [Jest's configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring) with CLI arg to "text-summary" or any other [alternative reporter](https://istanbul.js.org/docs/advanced/alternative-reporters/).

```sh
jest --coverageReporters="text-summary"
```

##### **`text-summary output:`**

```sh
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 100% ( 166/166 )
Branches     : 75% ( 18/24 )
Functions    : 100% ( 49/49 )
Lines        : 100% ( 161/161 )
================================================================================
```

Or you can write your own reporter.

Comment: summary was the keyword ;) Thanks for that!

Comment: "test": "jest --verbose --coverage --coverageReporters='text-summary'",

Comment: thank you so much, I wish I could upvote this more than once

Comment: thanks @jefelewis. This exact cmd works.

Answer (score 8):

I needed this myself, so I created a custom reporter. You need the json-summary reporter enabled in coverageReporters and then you can use this custom reporter to show the total:

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');

// Gitlab Regex: Total Coverage: (\d+\.\d+ \%)
module.exports = class CoverageReporter {
  constructor(globalConfig) {
    this.globalConfig = globalConfig;
    this.jsonSummary = join(this.globalConfig.coverageDirectory, 'coverage-summary.json');
  }
  async onRunComplete() {
    const coverage = require(this.jsonSummary);
    const totalSum = ['lines', 'statements', 'functions', 'branches']
      .map(i => coverage.total[i].pct)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
    const avgCoverage = totalSum / 4
    console.debug()
    console.debug('========= Total Coverage ============')
    console.debug(`Total Coverage: ${avgCoverage.toFixed(2)} %`)
    console.debug('=======================================')
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke this custom reporter?

Comment: Small issue: you are using the coverage-summary.json from previous run because CoverageReporter will always run after your custom reporter.


Edit: by CoverageReporter I mean Jest's one (https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/main/packages/jest-reporters/src/CoverageReporter.ts)